# replace keys in hashmap with the keys of other hashmap java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have got two hash maps. First is

```
 Map<String, ArrayList<String>> name = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

which contains name as the key and city as the value. Second is

```
 Map<String, ArrayList<String>> games = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

which contains city as the key and the list of games played per city as the value.

So, I want to compare the cities and if the cities match, then I want to assign list of games played as the value to name as key. I.e. I need a hash map which will have name as the key and list of games played as the value.

I really need some help here so please give detailed info as I am complete beginner to Java.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How could a city be an `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: Also given that city is an ArrayList<String> in #1, how can it match #2 where it just a string.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose,  ..my bad... city is a String.. sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first map should contain name as key and city as value instead of list of city.

With this assumption below code will work

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> nameGameListMap= new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    Iterator<String> it = name.keySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        String name = it.next();
        String city = name.get(name);
        if(games.containsKey(city))
        {
            nameGameListMap.put(name, games.get(city));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Map<String, List<String>> name = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> name1CityList = new ArrayList<String>();
name1CityList.add("city1");
name1CityList.add("city2");

List<String> name2CityList = new ArrayList<String>();
name2CityList.add("city2");

List<String> name3CityList = new ArrayList<String>();
name3CityList.add("city3");
name3CityList.add("city4");

name.put("name1", name1CityList);
name.put("name2", name2CityList);
name.put("name3", name3CityList);


Map<String, List<String>> games = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> city1GameList = new ArrayList<String>();
city1GameList.add("game1");
city1GameList.add("game2");
city1GameList.add("game3");

List<String> city2GameList = new ArrayList<String>();
city2GameList.add("game1");
city2GameList.add("game2");

List<String> city3GameList = new ArrayList<String>();
city3GameList.add("game2");
city3GameList.add("game3");

games.put("city1", city1GameList);
games.put("city2", city2GameList);
games.put("city2", city3GameList);

Map<String, List<String>> namegames = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> tempList;




for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : name.entrySet()) {
    tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String str : entry.getValue()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry_new : games.entrySet()) {
            if (str.equals(entry_new.getKey())) {
                    for(String str_new : entry_new.getValue()){
                        tempList.add(str_new);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    if(!tempList.isEmpty()){
        namegames.put(entry.getKey(), tempList);
    }
    tempList = null;
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : namegames.entrySet()) {
        for(String str : entry.getValue()){
            System.out.println("Name : "+entry.getKey()+"  Game :"+str);
        }
    }
```